# CSS Three columns grid

Tags: html, css, wordpress, grid

I'm editing a surfarama theme for Wordpress. And i've faced a tricky issue.
I want to make it full screen (by default it is 960px) and posts should be fitted into two or three fixed and aligned rows instead of floating weirdly.

To explain a little - there is a following structure 
a #**container** (or the main-wrap), 
.**grid-wrap** (which wraps the grid view),
 .**grid-box** (which formats the feautered type post) and 
.**latest** (which formats the latest type of post, which is bigger than the regular featured post)

What i do

i edit the **#container** id (change width to 100%).

```
#container { 
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0%;
    -webkit-box-sizing : border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing : border-box; 
    -o-box-sizing : border-box; 
    box-sizing : border-box; 
}
```

i remove any width constraints from .grid-wrap

and then i edit width in the сlass, responsible for the grid view .grid-box

```
.grid-box {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #359bed;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 11px 0; 
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

i change the width of the .latest class to fit my current resolution

```
.grid-box.featured:first-child,
.grid-box.latest {
    width: 1440px;
}
```

so considering the space - 1440px - three featured posts (300px + 300px + 300px + spaces) under the latest post (1440px) would fit nicely, but instead what i'm getting is

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JPr1.png

this theme also includes 320 and up adaptive resolution script - but i've tried editing it in a variety of ways, the posts do not fit in one row, they jump all over the place.

What could be the reason for it ? Float, display type or the grid specifics ?

Thank you so much.

Here is the original CSS stylesheet
http://surfarama.com/wp-content/themes/surfarama/style.css?ver=3.7.1

Comment: this is how i want it to look like http://i.imgur.com/bAQMwJ5.png

Comment: Could you upload your work on jsFiddle?

Comment: @rand0m http://jsfiddle.net/anL7u/
Thank you !

Comment: Hi, firstly I'm assuming that the CSS you pasted in that fiddle is modified version of surfarama right?

I was wondering why are you making changes to core CSS when you could write a stylesheet separately and overwrite css?

secondsly, I would suggest that you separate the grids in 2 separate divs. the 1st block in first div and the rest in another, which would make it easy to enlarge the div and highlight the content. For the second div, make its width 100% and its immediate contents width as 33.33% (for 3 cols), float them left and add some padding. That should give you desired result.

Comment: @rand0m That sounds like a great idea, although i have no clue how to separate two types of posts in code - 

`<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                 <?php
      $itm_class = '';
      if ( is_home() || is_archive() ) {
       if ( $surfarama_counter == 1 && !$wp_query->query_vars['paged'] ) {
        if ( is_sticky() ) {
         $itm_class = 'featured';
        } else {
         $itm_class = 'latest';
        }
       }
      }
      ?>
     <div class="grid-box <?php echo $itm_class; ?>">`

Comment: That code wouldn't probably work as it just adds a simple class to the grid-box div. Here's something I cooked up:

Lets assume that the posts are in an array:

$posts = array("0" => array("title"=>"test1", "content"=>"lorem ipsum 1", "posted_by"=>"admin"),"1" => array("title"=>"test2", "content"=>"lorem ipsum 2", "posted_by"=>"admin"),"2" => array("title"=>"test3", "content"=>"lorem ipsum 3", "posted_by"=>"admin")); // array of posts

You need to print the first item separately and the rest of them in a loop.

contd. in message below

Comment: print '<div class="row">';
 print '<div class="grid-box featured">'.$posts["0"]["content"].'</div>';
print '</div>';

print '<div class="row">';
 foreach(array_slice($posts, 1) as $p){
  print '<div class="grid-box latest">'.$p["content"].'</div>';
 }
print '</div>';


.row { display: block; width: 100%; margin-right: -15px; margin-left: -15px;} .row:after { clear: both; }

.latest{ display: block; width: 33.33%; padding-right: -15px; padding-left: -15px; }

hope this helps

Comment: ok, yet i'm not quite following where exactly the content should be placed. and also do i have to create a separate function for the array in "Theme functions.php" ?

Comment: Hi, sorry I can't be of any help, as I have no clue about word press.

usually, the code can be written in template which would render the html; I believe that you should have array of posts on page render, you could slice it or use the same array.

Comment: @rand0m anyway, it was very supportive. thank you. 
yet the question is still opened.